# How to keep track of changed values

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have a bluetooth device which keeps emitting data when it is started and stops emitting data when it pauses, I have RXJava subscriber attached to it to get the values.

What I want to do is check if the device is still running or paused. So for this I have a method getTotalizerChangedTime, this gives me the last updated time.

Based on getTotalizerChangedTime I want to check if the device is still running or not.

I want to check lastUpdatedTotalizerChangeTime and calculator.getLastTotalizerChangeTime() and if they both are same and time difference between them is 8 seconds (as every 8 seconds or so I get a value)

```
lastTotalizerChangeTime - 2019-09-04T18:33:40.781+01:00
lastTotalizerChangeTime - 2019-09-04T18:33:47.080+01:00
lastTotalizerChangeTime - 2019-09-04T18:33:57.592+01:00
lastTotalizerChangeTime - 2019-09-04T18:34:03.683+01:00
```

What I have tried is, I declared a variable to keep the last updated

private DateTime lastUpdatedTotalizerChangeTime = new DateTime();

I created a function which get the lastTotalizerChangeTime from getLastTotalizerChangeTime and does the following but does not work as expected.

Function that get the actual value

```
 public DateTime getLastTotalizerChangeTime() {
        return lastTotalizerChangeTime;
    }
```

I have declared a variable to keep the lastUpdatedChangedTime

```
private DateTime lastUpdatedTotalizerChangeTime = new DateTime();
```

Bellow is the function that gets called on button click which checks if the device is still running

```
private boolean hasFlowMeterFinishedPumping(){
  DateTime currentTime = new DateTime();
        Period differenceX = new Period(calculator.getLastTotalizerChangeTime(), currentTime);
        if(differenceX.getSeconds() >= 8 && lastUpdatedTotalizerChangeTime.equals(calculator.getLastTotalizerChangeTime())){
            Log.d("totaliserSenseCheck", "IF");
                    lastUpdatedTotalizerChangeTime = calculator.getLastTotalizerChangeTime();
            return true;
        }else{
            Log.d("totaliserSenseCheck", "else");
            lastUpdatedTotalizerChangeTime = calculator.getLastTotalizerChangeTime();
            return false;
        }
}
```

Logic I have written to track if the device stopped does not work as expected.

Your help much appreciated.

R

Comment: In what way *does not work as expected*, please? Does it, for example, always return true, always false, always the opposite of the correct, or apparently random results (that probably aren’t random in the end)?

Comment: Are those the `DateTIme` and `Period` classes from Joda-Time?

Comment: yes they are from Joda-Time. it is not the issue with the dateTime as such. but The logic itself. It works most part, but sometimes though the device is running, it gives me wrong result. 
when the device is running the function should return FALSE but it returns TRUE sometimes

Comment: So apparently it is sometimes the case that the last totalizer change time is more than 8 seconds ago and the same as last time, and yet the device is running. You might try with a greater tolerance of, say, 12 seconds, instead, though it will of course delay your detection of the device having stopped. Just a thought.